# Upload layers in Geoexplorer

Tags: geoexplorer

I have OGS 4.02, OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.I have questions about Geoexplorer. I know that anonymous users can not save and publish map and also they can not upload layers. If I create users which are in Geoserver admins (access mode is admin for specific workspace) or editors (access mode is write for specific workspace), why they can not upload their layers (zipped shapefiles) in their workspace, creating maybe even new stores on the fly. Why is that option only avaliable for one person, user with admin role? Is it something with folder security in Windows, is it necessary to create also users and specific folders for them. I know that after succesfull upload, two folders are created: one in C:\ProgramData\Boundless\OpenGeo\geoserver\uploads (tmp prefix) and another in workspace where data are uploaded. So who can only write in that folders through geoexplorer and geoserver port 8080? Is it necessary to create postgis store to enable upload for some power users (editors or small admins)?